# strncat off by one error - K&R C exercise 5-5

Tags: c, string, char, off-by-one

My version of strncat is copying one too many chars into the destination and I cannot figure out why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_CHARS 20

void nconcatenate(char *start, char *end, int n)
{
  if(sizeof start + n > MAX_CHARS)
    return;

  while(*start++);
  start--; /* now points to the final char of start, the \0 */
  int i;
  for(i = 0; (*start++ = *end++) && i < n; i++);
  *start = '\0';
}

int main()
{
  char start[MAX_CHARS] = "str";
  char *end = "ingy!";
  nconcatenate(start, end, 3);
  printf("start = %s\n", start);
  return 0;
}
```

Using 3 as 'n' outputs

```
stringy
```

which is one too many chars.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in the debugger?

Comment: `sizeof start` will always return `sizeof(char*)` btw.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I've tried with gdb although I am still very much a beginner in using it

Comment: @EdS. How would I check that the size of start + n is less than MAX_CHARS if I cannot use sizeof in the way I've used? I can only think of passing the function another argument but I'd rather not do that.

Comment: @CSStudent You can use strlen.

Comment: @FlorinPetriuc strlen will be perfect

Comment: @EdS.: There are two things named `start`. The one in `nconcatenate` is a pointer, and yes, `sizeof start` in that function will yield `sizeof (char*)`. There's also an array named `start` in `main`; `sizeof start` in `main` will yield `MAX_CHARS`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe because in the condition

```
(*start++ = *end++) && i < n
```

first it does (*start++ = *end++) and after that, it checks i < n.

I haven't tested it, but check it out and see.

Comment: Fantastic, that has fixed it, I would never of spotted that. Thank you